# messagebox and timer in visual studio

Tags: timer, messagebox

Need help. 
so i was making a game with my friend for college using visual studio 2017 and there's something weird about the program. 
we're set it so that when the life is zero, a message box would show up and chose whether to retry the game or not, but when we tried the game, the message box show's up at least at 20 - 30 second after playing the game and the timer for the game is still going even though we add "timergame.enable = false;".
where's seems to be the problem?

```
private void timerGame_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfSardine.Count; i++)
        {
            listOfSardine[i].Top += (int)listOfSardine[i].Tag;
            if (listOfSardine[i].Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBoxGrass.Bounds))
            {
                userLives--;
                labelLives.Text = "Lives: " + userLives;
                listOfSardine[i].Dispose();
                listOfSardine.RemoveAt(i);
                if (userLives == 0)
                {
                    highScore = userScore;
                    timerBonusSpeed.Enabled = false;
                    timerGame.Enabled = false;
                    timerHealth.Enabled = false;
                    timerMatatabi.Enabled = false;
                    timerSardine.Enabled = false;

                    DialogResult dialogResultLose = MessageBox.Show
                        ("Sorry.... you have lost, continue?", "Continue??", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                    if (dialogResultLose == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < listOfHealth.Count; j++)
                        {
                            listOfHealth[j].Dispose();
                        }
                        listOfHealth.Clear();
                        for (int q = 0; q < listOfSardine.Count; q++)
                        {
                            listOfSardine[q].Dispose();
                        }
                        listOfSardine.Clear();
                        for (int k = 0; k < listOfMatatabi.Count; k++)
                        {
                            listOfMatatabi[k].Dispose();
                        }
                        listOfMatatabi.Clear();

                        userLives = USER_LIVES;
                        userScore = USER_SCORE;

                        timerBonusSpeed.Enabled = true;
                        timerGame.Enabled = true;
                        timerHealth.Enabled = true;
                        timerMatatabi.Enabled = true;
                        timerSardine.Enabled = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.Visible = false;
                        FormMainMenu formMainMenu = new FormMainMenu();
                        formMainMenu.Owner = this;
                        formMainMenu.ShowDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (listOfSardine[i].Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBoxMainCharacter.Bounds))
            {
                listOfSardine[i].Dispose();
                listOfSardine.RemoveAt(i);
                userScore += 1;
                labelScore.Text = "Score: " + userScore;
                if (userScore % 100 == 0)
                {
                    listOfSardine[i].Top += (int)listOfSardine[i].Tag * 4;
                }
                if(userScore == 1000)
                {
                    timerBonusSpeed.Enabled = false;
                    timerGame.Enabled = false;
                    timerHealth.Enabled = false;
                    timerMatatabi.Enabled = false;
                    timerSardine.Enabled = false;
                    highScore = userScore;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                listOfSardine[i].Refresh();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfHealth.Count; i++)
        {
            listOfHealth[i].Top += (int)listOfHealth[i].Tag;
            if (listOfHealth[i].Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBoxGrass.Bounds))
            {
                listOfHealth[i].Dispose();
                listOfHealth.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            else if (listOfHealth[i].Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBoxMainCharacter.Bounds))
            {
                listOfHealth[i].Dispose();
                listOfHealth.RemoveAt(i);
                userLives++;
                labelLives.Text = "Lives: " + userLives;
            }
            else
            {
                listOfHealth[i].Refresh();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough clear what you did. However, I think you have a counter for life, and which are decreasing as per your game's event. On timer event just check life counter is equal or less than Zero or not. If so, just stop timer, give user confirmation for retry. If user want to retry, then reset life counter and start timer.

Comment: I am not exactly sure. But as per your code, you are checking life (life count) first. And after getting zero you did not use return keyword, for this reason rest of code executing, and also increasing life and continuing timer. On end of life use return keyword (after formMainMenu.ShowDialog();) to prevent execute rest of code, or check life count at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh already found the answer
our problem is about the ownership of the form, we just incorrectly insert the ownership for each form
thanks for the people who have answered my question earlier